# Why won't `gpio` work from an init script?

Tags: gpio, led, script, init.d

I have an init.d script that successfully runs scripts to an LED board from Adafruit using this software: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix

In addition, I've set up a simple single LED circuit and can operate it using this software: https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/

When I run my gpio script for the LED it has no problems. When I run the loop to do both at the same time, no issues. All as user pi.

When init.d runs the loop on startup, the gpio script called up inside other scripts doesn't appear to run. It doesn't seem to set the pins to where they can be written to. When the loop is running, it should set

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 26 out
end=$((SECONDS+20))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do 
  gpio write 26 1
  sleep 2
  gpio write 26 0
  sleep 1
done
```

But it does not appear that the settings are changed when I use the gpio program to check `gpio readall`

What is likely the culprit here? The script works just fine when run either as user `pi` or as `sudo` just not through `init.d` or root.

Comment: I can't see how we can help without visibility of the script(s) you are running.

Comment: I can provide the scripts, but I'm not sure they're _that_ relevant since they run when executed normally. But fair point, I just don't have them backed up here at work.

Comment: If something runs "normally" but not from a boot script it is usually because the paths aren't identical.  Are you using absolute path names for any programs and code you are using, e.g. where is gpio on the filesystem, are you using gpio or /usr/bin/gpio or whatever.

Comment: The most common cause of this is it isn't running at all because of paths or a dud init script.  You should incorporate some logging so you can confirm this and report any errors that may occur.

Comment: These are good suggestions. gpio was installed by a friend of mine, I'll have to check where. It makes sense if I can find where it's installed and change the script (now recreated above) to that.

Comment: Add `exec &> /var/log/test.log` (you need privileges for that, but init scripts run root) and a simple `echo "Running!"` to the top of that bash script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general question about Linux, and not specific to the Pi. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Gpio is specific to the Raspberry Pi and it's about software for raspberry pi.

Comment: Milliways is right.  Unless you can demonstrate your script is running but there is a specific error with the GPIOs, this is just another "How do I do something properly at boot?" question (or "I swear I did it properly and it still won't work...what's the problem?").   As is, joan's answer is about all you are going to get.  If that doesn't help you are going to have to do some debugging of your own to provide details about what actually is and is not happening.

Comment: Joan's answer is correct, though. I knew I was missing something obvious and the thing I was missing was related to RPi specific software. I also didn't know if something with the hzeller program was interfering somehow, so I included that. If you would like me to reword the question, I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default wiringPi's gpio utility is installed in /usr/local/bin.

It is unlikely to be in the path of the root user when init scripts are run.

Rather than gpio use /usr/local/bin/gpio.